# Unit testing in boilerplate framework application with angular and asp.net core

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, boilerplate

i am developing boilerplate application with asp.net core and angular 2, here i struck at unit testing in asp.net core solution. while doing unit testing my code is not hitting the real database. the test cases are running for only mock data which i have given in seed folder in asp.net core solution.

please give me a solution to hit real database and based on that real database records my unit test cases should work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi! Which DB are you using and how is it set up? Are you using EF Core or something else?

Comment: I am using EF core.